# When do I know to cause a rebuffer on streaming audio when playing over ALSA?

Tags: c++, audio, streaming, buffer, alsa

My program takes streaming opus data and plays it immediately over a speaker system. The data is written via one thread that receives it and played on another that either continues to loop through the audio while there is buffer or gets blocked by a conditional variable until buffer activity. It does this until "done_" is set to "true" on the audio object and the buffer becomes empty, at which point it breaks (out of the loop and picks up another stream to play).

In this example, the audio is buffering for buffer_needed_ amount of bytes. When the buffer size hits the limit, it will start playing. This works sort of because snd_pcm_writei actually has its own internal circular buffer that pulls as much audio as possible. So the program runs out of buffer in *current_audio* and thinks we had an underrun.

To fix this, I tried checking to see the size of the buffer of ALSA by running snd_pcm_avail_update, but that just runs how much data is available in the buffer, not how much data is written to the buffer in ALSA.

So there are three unique things that puzzle me when they come together:

1. The conditional variable really only unblocks when there is data. So that means there will 90% of the time be at least one decodable 20ms chunk.
2. ALSA has its own buffer.
3. I'm using my own buffer.

My question is then, how will I truly know when ALSA has run out of audio in writei and by the time I get to my internal buffer testing, that it's time to do a re-buffer?

```
{ // For the lock context
    // Lock the buffer 'cause we'll need of it
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> buffer_lock( current_audio->buffer_mutex_ );

    while( true )
    {
        // We need a positive lock
        if( !buffer_lock )
            buffer_lock.lock();

        bool has_enough=false;

        // See if we need to wait on the buffer
        if( current_audio->buffer_state_==Audio::BufferBuffering and
                (current_audio->done_ or
                 current_audio->buffer_->size()>=current_audio->buffer_needed_) )
        {
            LOG_TRACE( *logger_ ) << "Buffer started.";
            current_audio->buffer_state_ = Audio::BufferStarted;
        }

        if( current_audio->buffer_state_!=Audio::BufferBuffering )
        {
            // Do we need to rebuffer?
            if( current_audio->buffer_state_==Audio::BufferStarted and
                    !current_audio->done_ and
                    snd_pcm_avail_update( playback_handle_ )<=0 and
                    current_audio->buffer_->size()<current_audio->buffer_needed_ )
            {
                // Do we not have enough for the next chunk?
                current_audio->buffer_state_ = Audio::BufferBuffering; // Go back to the buffering state
                LOG_TRACE( *logger_ ) << "Buffer underrun. Causing rebuffer.";
            }
            else
            {

                has_enough = audioCanDecodeChunk( current_audio, payload_size );

            }
        }

        // Now fisticuffs do we have enouffs?
        if( has_enough )
        {
            // We have enough!
            // Read to the payload buffer
            current_audio->buffer_->read( payload_buffer.get(), (size_t)payload_size );

            // Release it
            buffer_lock.unlock();

            // Now thingify it
            int samples_decoded = opus_decode( opus_decoder_,
                    (const unsigned char *)payload_buffer.get(),
                    payload_size,
                    (opus_int16 *)pcm_buffer.get(),
                    MAX_FRAME_SIZE,
                    0 );

            // How did we do?
            if( samples_decoded<0 )
            {
                // What hap?
                LOG_ERROR( *logger_ ) << "Error decoding samples: " << opus_strerror( samples_decoded );
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Now we have our PCM!
                //int bytes_decoded = current_audio->recording_.channels*sizeof( opus_int16 )*samples_decoded;

                error = snd_pcm_writei( playback_handle_, pcm_buffer.get(), samples_decoded );

                if( error==-EINTR )
                {
                    // Reset the write
                    error = 0;
                }
                else if( error==-EPIPE )
                {
                    // Underrun!?
                    if( snd_pcm_prepare( playback_handle_)>=0 )
                        error = snd_pcm_writei( playback_handle_, pcm_buffer.get(), samples_decoded ); // Rerun
                }

                // Now write
                if( error<0 )
                {
                    // Attempt to resume if suspended for some reason
                    if( snd_pcm_state(playback_handle_)==SND_PCM_STATE_SUSPENDED )
                    {
                        /* Whydidthishappenhere? */
                        snd_pcm_resume( playback_handle_ );

                        if( snd_pcm_state(playback_handle_)==SND_PCM_STATE_SUSPENDED )
                        {
                            // Saving sessions?
                            LOG_ERROR( *logger_ ) << "snd_pcm_resume did not clear the suspended state.";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        LOG_ERROR( *logger_ ) << "snd_pcm_writei error: " << snd_strerror( error );
                }
            }

            // Empty the payload
            payload_size = PAYLOAD_EMPTY;

        } // If we don't have enough let it slide and unlock
        else if( current_audio->done_ ) // Were we issued a flush?
        {
            // We are done with this loop
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            current_audio->wait_buffer_.wait( buffer_lock );
        }

    } // End while( true )

} // End lock context
```

As a side note, I've been trying to look a bunch for some lightweight C++ code concerning buffering and playing streaming audio, but haven't found one yet. I'm just missing something somewhere.

Comment: Is is important that you release the output device if packets stop coming in? Otherwise it's probably easier to just keep the output running and mix in external data whenever it comes by. This way you'll be constantly dealing with underruns on the output device.